# Error when trying to separating class into .h, .cpp

Tags: c++

This is a minimal program that I made to understand this problem better.

ADT.h

```
#ifndef ADT_H
#define ADT_H

class ADT {    
public:
      void print();
};

#endif
```

ADT.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ADT.h"

using namespace std;

void ADT::print()
{
   cout << "This program works." << endl;
}
```

testADT.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ADT.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
   ADT sa;
   sa.print();

   return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with the vim/minGW compiler my school provided me like so:

```
g++ testADT.cpp
```

Which produced the following error:

```
C:\Users\King\AppData\Local\Tempcc6eoWAP.o:testADT.cpp(.text+0x15 reference to 'ADT::print()'
collect2.exe error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can you explain this error message and indicate the error in my code?

Comment: That's not an error, that's what you typed to compile it. What error did you get?

Comment: updated error message

Comment: If you're trying to build an object file (`testADT.o`) then you should use the `-c` flag. If you're trying to build an executable, you must link in `ADT.o` (or pass both source files to the compiler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post the error, but I see that you're missing the semicolon after `void print()`in the header.

EDIT: That's a linker error. Each source file should be compiled into an object file; then the object files linked:

```
g++ -c -oADT.o ADT.cpp
g++ -c -otestADT.o testADT.cpp
g++ -oADT ADT.o testADT.o
```

You can also do it in one line as in michaeltang's answer, but then you can't recompile the sources individually (the 2 step method scales better).

Answer (score 2):

You should also compile `ADT.cpp`

```
g++ -o testadt testADT.cpp  ADT.cpp
```